# PlayFramework how to show details of java object in view

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

i am playing around with play and dont know how I can acces my java objects in the view. In the controller I am creating a list and render this list

```
public static void index() {

    List <SendAllSysParameter> paras = SendAllSysParameter.findAll();
    render(paras);
}
```

The SendallSysParameter Object is my model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="SendAll_SysParameter")
public class SendAllSysParameter extends GenericModel
{

@Id
@Column(name = "sendAllKey", unique = true, nullable = false)
public String sendAllKey;

@Column(name = "sendAllValue")
public String sendAllValue;

@Column(name = "sendAllDate", nullable = false, length = 23)
public Timestamp sendAllDate;



}
```

In the view can now show the list of sendAllKey-Values. But how can I show also the sendAllValue-Value in the view?

Here is my view:

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Home' /}
<ul>
#{list paras, as:'elem'}
  <li>&{elem}</li>
#{/list}
</ul>
```

As a JS-Noob I do not know how to handle this in the view. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the list:

```
<ul>
#{list items:paras, as:'elem' }
  <li>${elem.sendAllKey}</li>
  <li>${elem.sendAllValue}</li>
  <li>${elem.sendAllDate}</li>
#{/list}
</ul>
```

Any time you want to access a variable passed by the Controller, you'll use `${varName}`, not `&{varName}`